# Kibana JSON input regex query - show only first 100 charectors

Tags: json, regex, kibana-4

I am not able to figure out how to run regex query in Kibana to get the first 100 characters of string.
Currently i have field error which is 500+ char long and it does screw up my table while displaying, i want to display only first 100 characters in table.

Comment: The regex to match the first 100 chars would be: `^.{100}`

Comment: What code are you using? If the regex is of ElasticSearch flavor, you need something like `((.|\n){100}).*` to be able to grab any first 100 chars incl. a newline (all ES patterns are anchored).